# What do the enumerable and configurable properties do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I saw this snippet of code in Javascript:

```
Object.defineProperty(Pet.prototype, "petName", {
    get: function () {
        return this.petName;
    },
    set: function (petName) {
        this.petName = petName;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

This appears to be an accessor method of a property in Javascript. But what I don't understand is the `enumerable: true` and `configurable: true`. I searched the web, but I still can't quite understand what is written in the Mozilla documentation. I tried setting them to false, and it seems like I can still access the property with no problem and it doesn't seem like there is a difference.

What exactly do the `enumerable` and `configurable` properties here do to the accessor method? Will be nice if there is an example to illustrate their purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [MDN documentation for `Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> **enumerable**
>
> true if and only if this property shows up during
>   enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.

i.e. does it show up in a `for ... in` loop, in `Object.keys`, etc.

> **configurable**
>
> true if and only if the type of this property descriptor
>   may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the
>   corresponding object.

e.g. if `configurable` is set to `false` then you cannot subsequently modify the property's descriptor, perhaps to change it back to non-`enumerable`, or `writable`

See also the [ES5 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.1).

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.1 (Also, for.. in loop is not the only way to enumerate object keys)

Comment: @PaulS. it's not the property that you can't then modify, it's the property _descriptor_.

Comment: @Alnitak keep forgetting _writable_ defaults to `false` too

Comment: @Alnitak Just to clarify, by *property descriptor*, you mean the *data type* of the property? So the data type cannot be changed if it is false, did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Carven the "type" of the property isn't part of the descriptor, it's the rest of the fields described in the MDN page I linked to.